# How to add Fix amount charge in percentage wise in shopping cart price rule?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

- in magento 1 provide by default "Percent of product price discount" i want create "percent of product price add charge".
- I override validator.php file and gets the discount amount on that but I don't know which place I calculate and add a charge for that.

please help me on this action.
thank you in advance.

Comment: This wont serve your purpose but you can download this extension and see how i did things there. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multidiscount-coupon-code.html